# Await is the Only Async function : API NODE

Tags: node.js, sql-server, rest, api

I'm unable the below snippet of code. I tried calling an async function, but I'm getting an error as shown below.I'm trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server.
Please review the code, and please inform me what is the with the these code snippet.

```
**SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function**


var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sql = require('mssql');

async function connectDB(){

 const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(global.config.sqlConfig);
     try {
         await pool.connect();
         console.log('Connected to DATABASE');
         return pool;
     }
     catch(err){
         console.log('conn failure');
         return err;
     }
};

async function executeQuery(req, res){    
 const DB = await connectDB(); 
 try{
     var result = await DB.request()
     .query(req).then(function () {
        console.log("QUERY PASSED");
        console.log(result.recordset);
        return result.recordset;
     });

 }
 catch(err){
     console.log("ERROR QUERYing DATABASE");
     return err;
 }
 finally{
      DB.close();
 }

 };

router.get('/login', function (req, res) {   
   var strquery = "select fUserPwd from tblUser where fUserID ='ADMIN'";
    console.log(strquery);
   const result = await executeQuery(strquery, res); 
   res.send(result);     

});

module.exports = router;
```

I wanted the recordset to be get displayed on opening the link. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: change this line const pool = await new sql.ConnectionPool(global.config.sqlConfig); then use pool.connect inside try{}

Comment: @vitomadio the error is occurring when it’s executing const result = await executeQuery(strQuery,res);

Comment: Of course,  you're missing async before function, in  router.get('/login', async function (req, res) {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in this route.

```
   router.get('/login',async function (req, res) {   
       var strquery = "select fUserPwd from tblUser where fUserID ='ADMIN'";
        console.log(strquery);
       const result = await executeQuery(strquery, res); 
       res.send(result);     

    });
```